# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED : Error when launch the app on Android phone

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have got the error below when I launch my app on my Android phone (I compile it on my phone with `ionic cordova run android`).

```
Application Error 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://192.165.1.5:8101)
```

In first launch, the app works well. But after, like 10min, I close the app, and reopen it and now the app show the error at every launch.
I would like to know in which case I can I have this error, how to solve it and if it's possible to have this error in production?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below CLI for that.

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```

*Production build*

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know why this error in debug mode... And is this will not happen in production with the command line you provide.

Comment: The CLI which I gave is also for the debug mode.On debug mode, these things can happen due to network issues on the local server.But it won't happen on the production.Please see the production build CLI on my post.